# Android MusicXML parser

Tags: parsing, musicxml

I build app for drawing notes in android using MusicXML and I look for some quality parser to extract all the necessary information to do it.

How I can parse MusicXML (.mxl) in Android? (some library?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to parse the files using a standard XML parser available in Android. With .mxl files you need to parse the zip file, then parse the XML content inside it. One advantage of using XML for MusicXML is that there are XML parsers available on just about every platform, without requiring music-specific software. Android doesn't yet support music apps as well as iOS, so there are fewer music-specific SDKs, like SeeScore, available on Android compared to iOS.